# How to set NumberOfWorkers, WorkerType as G2X in AWS Glue via airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I am trying to create a glue job with this configuration 'NumberOfWorkers': 10, 'WorkerType': 'G.2X'. Here's my code for job creation.

```
glue_job_step = AwsGlueJobOperator(
job_name=glue_job_name,
job_desc="AWS Glue Job with Airflow",
script_location="s3://\<bucket_name\>/scripts/test_spark_hello.py",
create_job_kwargs={'GlueVersion': '3.0', 'NumberOfWorkers': 10, 'WorkerType': 'G.2X'},
num_of_dpus=10,
concurrent_run_limit=1,
script_args=None,
retry_limit=0,
region_name=region_name,
s3_bucket="s3_bucket_name",
iam_role_name=glue_iam_role,
run_job_kwargs=None,
wait_for_completion=True,
task_id='glue_job_step',
dag=dag
)
```

And I am facing the following error:

```
Failed to run aws glue job, error: An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateJob operation: Please do not set Allocated Capacity if using Worker Type and Number of Workers.
```

Note:

1. If i remove 'NumberOfWorkers' and 'WorkerType' the job is working with G1.X workers and 10 worker nodes.  But just wondering how to upgrade to G2.X Workers.
2. I am using AWS MWAA for airflow infrastructure.